# Copy files reverted on synchronisation

Tags: android-studio

I copy files from Explorer and paste them in Project view, replacing existing files. As soon as I press the Synchronize button (or wait a few seconds) the files get reverted, the action gets undone. Like they are in a memory cache that "corrects" the disk content.
Any pointer?

Comment: I copy/paste drawable-xxx folders ie legitimate editable files

Comment: They are valid. If I close Studio, paste and open Studio everything is ok. There must be something regarding disk vs memory cache.